# f8 and f9 brightness key not working for eluktronics/clevo 16.04

Tags: 16.04, laptop, brightness, function-keys, nvidia-geforce

Current state of my /etc/default/grub from other solutions is:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi="
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

and still nothing changes. My F5 and F6 work for changing volume. 
I have an Eluktronics premium laptop with NVIDIA Gerforce GTX 1050 if that helps.
Anyone know what else to try?

EDIT: vender -> vendor

Comment: "Vender"?!? Try **vendor**.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Sorry, I actually copy/pasted this time. But it does say "vendor" in file.